# How do I retrieve and modify AttachedContentNote objects attached to a record?

Tags: rest-api, contentnote

So I've created a custom object and added the Notes to available related lists on the page layout. Now I want to manage notes through the REST API.

[image]

The problem is, I have no idea how to access the notes. I found a suggestion that `AttachedContentNote` is a wrapper around `ContentNote`, and that seems to be supported by the fact that I can see my note under `services/data/v43.0/sobjects/ContentNote/listviews/00B2v00000Osr6REAR/results`, but that doesn't link it to the custom object records, which is what I assume `AttachedContentNote` does.

The problem is that I can't seem to find the `AttachedContentNote` object. I've looked at [AttachedContentNote docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachedcontentnote.htm) and it indicates that there is a `LinkedEntityId` field, but using this in a query (e.g. `services/data/v43.0/sobjects/AttachedContentNote/LinkedEntityId/00B2v00000Osr6R`) tells me that the field doesn't exist or isn't accessible (the access token belongs to the system administrator user, so I assume it doesn't exist).

On further reading, I've noticed that the documentation for AttachedContentNode states the following, which doesn't clear up how to actually access the notes:

> To retrieve ContentNote objects, issue a describe call on an object, which returns a query result for each note created or attached. You can’t directly query this object.

How do I list and access notes belonging to a given entity? If I have custom object id X, how do I find, create, and update, etc. content note Y using REST?

Comment: The notes are simply a `ContentDocument` with `FileType` as `SNOTE`. So you can use SOQL against `ContentDocumentLink` with related query to `ContentDocument` fields.

Comment: @zaitsman is SOQL the only way? No REST endpoint without a query?

Comment: Soql can be run through rest? I don’t know about other endpoints, i use soql for everything, all objects :)

Comment: @zaitsman I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AttachedContentNote` does not support query operation.

**To find related notes for an object:**

Execute a query on `ContentDocumentLink` through REST GET call as follows to retrieve `ContentDocument` of type 'SNOTE' for your custom object

`https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/query/?q=SELECT+id,ContentDocument.Title,+ContentDocumentId+FROM+ContentDocumentLink+where+LinkedEntityId+in+(+SELECT+Id+FROM+YourCustomObject__c)+and+ContentDocument.FileType+=+'SNOTE'`

Replace `YourCustomObject__c` by your custom object API name.

It is recommended to filter further the inner query `SELECT Id FROM YourCustomObject__c` so that you do not exceed limits.

**To create `ContentNote` object via REST API**

For example perform a POST call to `https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentNote`

Add relevant fields in the request body

```
{
"Title" : "Your note",
"FileType" : "SNOTE", ....
}
```

Note that `Content` field in `ContentNote` must be in base64.

When a `ContentNote` is created, a `ContentDocumentLink` record is automatically created to link the note with the user performing the operation.

To link it to another record, create another `ContentDocumentLink` record via a POST request

`https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentDocumentLink`

```
{
"ContentDocumentId" :"0691t00000WoZc8AAF",
"LinkedEntityId" : "a001t00000GQdDdAAL", 
"ShareType" : "I"
}
```

where `ContentDocumentId` matches the id returned after creating ContentNote, 
`LinkedEntityId` matches your custom object record,
`ShareType` determines the sharing access, refer to the documentation for more details about possible values

**References**

[ContentNote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm)
[ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm#topic-title)
[ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm)
[Create record using REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm)
[Update record via REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm)

Comment: If I create a `ContentNote` via REST, how do I associate it with `YourCustomObject__c`?

Comment: @John you need to perform another create operation to insert a `ContentDocumentLink` and associate it with your custom object record id. I've edited the last section of the answer to provide more details about this

Comment: I see. Makes sense. Thanks Shamina! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to already accepted answer:

using composite request, below is payload:

uri: /services/data/v50.0/composite
method: POST
payload:

```
{
    "allOrNone" : true,
    "compositeRequest": [{
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Case",
        "referenceId": "newCase",
        "body": {
            "RecordTypeId":"0120W000001pOoDQAU",
            "Type": "Vending Repair"
        }
    },{
        "method" : "POST",
        "url" : "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/ContentNote",
        "referenceId" : "newNote",
        "body" : {
            "Title" : "Harrison-Title",
            "Content" : "SGFycmlzb24tQm9keQ=="
        }
    },{
        "method" : "POST",
        "url" : "/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/ContentDocumentLink",
        "referenceId" : "newCDL",
        "body" : {
            "LinkedEntityId" : "@{newCase.id}",
            "ContentDocumentId" : "@{newNote.id}"
        }
    }]
}
```